# Is there a google voice api for sending text messages?

Tags: c#, google-voice

Does anyone know of any working gvoice api? I have found this project:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gvoicedotnet/
but the login appears to no longer work since the url changed some months ago.

Does anyone have a good question for sending out text messages to users of my website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found one: SharpGoogleVoice.
https://bitbucket.org/jitbit/sharpgooglevoice/downloads

It only has text messaging support, but it works well and looks like good work.

Answer (score 3):

Self-promotion: my API, SharpVoice, works/worked quite well (hasn't been tested in some time): https://github.com/descention/sharp-voice

`Voice voiceConnection = new Voice(loginEmail, loginPassword);
string response = voiceConnection.SendSMS(smsToPhoneNumber, smsMsgBody);`

Comment: You should add your lib to Nuget.

Comment: Thanks for writing this API!  I can only get one message to display using your sample program.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The message thread is not contained in the JSON, which the library parses. It's held in the HTML and I've never gotten around to parsing that out. It's a known issue.

Comment: Do you have a recommended change? What makes this answer different from Kyle's answer?

Comment: Please explain how to use it, when I surf to GitHub I don't find any Wikis, you might want to add one.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an SMS gateway that will let you send out text messages via an API. A quick Google search yields [Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/), which lets developers send SMS text messages for free from their application.

Because it's free, there may very well be some restrictions, but if you architect your app correctly using a strategy or adapter pattern then you should be able to replace this module later on down the road with something more advanced based on the needs of your application.

The primary restriction on the free plan is that it's ad-supported. This may very well be ok for you during initial development and testing, but your production users will likely find this to be a significant problem in using your service. Zeep does have a paid plan that eliminates the ads, and there are of course countless other SMS gateways that have API's that you can use for a fee.

Answer (score -1):

You can get [send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) with Twilio.

An example using the C# helper library:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/csharp

```
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
    string AuthToken = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var message = twilio.SendMessage(
        "+15017250604", "+15558675309",
        "Hey Kyle! Glad you asked this question.",
        new string[] { "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg" }
    );
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
 }
}
```